# Introduce new line in the cell value

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

---

1. 'abc def  ghi' but we want out put like in sql server
2. abc
      def
      ghi

Comment: Try to use a user-defined split function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the forum and read up on the help centre to find out how to ask a question. We are here to help troubleshoot your code. Please update your question with what you have done and someone can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `</RowData></XMLRoot>` Like below Example:

```
DECLARE @StringList NVARCHAR(8000)

SET @StringList = 'abc def ghi'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)'))) AS NAME
FROM (
    SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(@StringList, ' ', '</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS t
    ) tbl
CROSS APPLY t.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m(n)
```

Comment: He does not want the single row to be split in multiple rows. He wants to introduce new line in the same row for each string that is separated by a space in that row.

Answer (score -1):

You probably cannot view this in 'Results to Grid Mode'.
So, Switch to 'Results to Text' and run the below

```
select REPLACE('abc def ghi',' ',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, you already have the value 'abc def ghi' in a single row.right? You want abc in one row,def in 2nd and ghi in 3rd row, right?

Comment: no abc in one row def in same row ghi in same row. please you can see added image in question. please help me